# C# make method required

Tags: c#, oop, class, methods

I have a class with a method that when not called causes a crash.

Is there a way to make a compilation failure when the method isn't called?

**Edit:**

So what I have is basically a class that makes an istance of another class (a form) and it is a mesagebox with a do not show again option.  Here's an example of how you'd use it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    DontShowAgainBox box;
    public void AlertYes() {
        if (box.form.showagain.Checked)
            t1.Text = "You chose yes (checked)!!!";
        else
            t1.Text = "You chose yes (unchecked)!!!";
    }
    public void AlertNo() {
        if (box.form.showagain.Checked)
            t1.Text = "You chose no (checked)!!!";
        else
            t1.Text = "You chose no (unchecked)!!!";
    }
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        box = new DontShowAgainBox("Warning", "Are you sure?");

        Action yesaction = new Action(AlertYes);
        box.Bind_Yes(yesaction);

        Action noaction = new Action(AlertNo);
        box.Bind_No(noaction);

        box.SetNoButton("Nope");
        box.SetYesButton("I'm sure");

        box.Show();
    }
}
```

There's another method that you can hide the "No" button with also.

But the yes button is in every instance of the class so it needs to have a function associated with it or else... crash.

Comment: please provide a code sample/snippet.

Comment: Not sure I understand - if it causes an error when you don't call it, why don't you call it in the constructor (if its not a static class)

Comment: @Mark: Isn't called in what context?  When does the method need to be called?  And how is the _default_ state of the application a crash?

Comment: Could you create a simple example project which explains what you're trying to do? Usually this is solved by changing the design of your application (as in, architecture) instead of trying to jump through hoops to get it checked at compile time.

Comment: The question should be "How do I refactor this so the user's program won't crash if the user doesn't call this method".

Comment: Why not calling it from the constructor? in this case you make sure it gets called for each object you create. What you want is not possible, and not useful either, because you probably want to make sure the method is called for each object, not simply just called somewhere, sometime.

Comment: I added an example and I guess yes I could put it in the constructor but I'd rather have it in it's own method.  If it's impossible than I guess the other way is the way to go.

Comment: You can have it it it's own method and call this method from your constructor.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'd rather have it be called by the user in it's own method but: **Is it possible** if it is impossible then someone should just say that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for the compiler or linker to say, at build time, "Hey, this method that was supposed to be called wasn't called!" You can't make the compiler issue an error message because client code didn't call a particular method.

What you're asking is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just test for this in software instead of crashing?

```
if (!init_called) { 
   print error
   exit
}
```

Comment: Or another option: if (!init_called) Initialize();